# Laravel sql server change table name for schema

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on a project and i'm trying to set some tables with a schema on my SQL Server Data Base, so i manually change the tables name to the schema_name.table_name on the migration file and it worked, so here is an example:

```
Schema::create('electoral.centro_votacions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('id_estado');

        $table->bigInteger('id_municipio');

        $table->bigInteger('id_parroquia');

        $table->bigInteger('id');

        $table->string('nombre');

        $table->longText('direccion');

        $table->foreign(['id_parroquia','id_municipio','id_estado'])->references(['id','id_municipio','id_estado'])->on('electoral.parroquias');
        $table->primary('id');
});
```

But when i'm trying to make a eloquent query on php `php artisan tinker` it doesn't work i just get an error saying, for example making a query `App\CentroVotacion::all();`:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'centro_votacions'. (SQL: select * from [centro_votacions])'

Of course I get it there is no table "centro_votacions" there is a table called "electoral.centro_votacions", so the thing, is how can i make laravel change the query so that i can find the "electoral.centro_votacions" table and other schemas on my SQL Server DB?.

Comment: share your CentroVotacion model too. But probably inside CentroVotacion model  under class name if you write `protected $table = 'electoral.centro_votacions';` you'll be fine

Comment: that actually seems to worked, but when i make the query i don't get a json i get this `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#29709}`

Comment: post your query

Comment: never mind i forgot the ->get(), your solution worked perfectly

Comment: since my suggestion solved your problem I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside `CentroVotacion` model define table name

```
class CentroVotacion extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'electoral.centro_votacions';
```

Comment: hello. what about if we want a schema_name based on environment?
(production vs local)

Comment: thank you for this. My only problem now is when i use the auth, the register controller will yield error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237416/laravel-sql-issue-on-5-5-auth-validation