# Laravel 5.5 SQL Migration Issue

Tags: laravel, migration, ssms

I'm fairly new to Laravel, my question is every-time i run a migration on SQL database, the defined schema on SQL Management Server Studio is the login windows user, Can I change the schema to something else?

Currently, running migration will create a table like this:

```
Asia\user123.migration
```

I need to create a table with the following schema

```
APP.migration
```

EDIT:
if anyone needs the solution for this problem, just update the schema create before running migrations and adding it on the User model

[Laravel sql server change table name for schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003152/laravel-sql-server-change-table-name-for-schema)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood the question, but I think you need the following solution:

Create a schema first for your application in MySQL. Open up the terminal and type `mysql -u root -p` then hit enter. Type in your mysql password and hit enter again. Then type `CREATE DATABASE app;` enter. Then you can exit with the command `exit`, enter. Then in your `.env` file set `DB_DATABASE=app`.

Comment: there is no problem connecting to database, Migration is already creating a table. My concern is it is creating a different schema name when i run the migration.

Comment: Try it this way, and it won't create a new schema. (or at least it shouldn't)

Comment: is it the same with SQL?

Comment: This is SQL, but more controllable way than using a GUI tool

Comment: Or did you mean, that you have different type of database? (Like MSSQL, or Postgres?)

Comment: hi, thanks for your help but i manage to answer my question. Thank you again