# Laravel SQL issue on 5.5 Auth Validation

Tags: sql, laravel, schema

From a fresh project, I tried to rename the "users" table to "app.users".

I managed to update migrations by updating schema::create

`Schema::create('app.users', function (Blueprint $table){});
 Schema::create('app.password_resets', function (Blueprint $table){});`

and updated the user.php model by changing

`protected $table = 'app.users';`

my only problem is when I try to register, it yields an error :`Database [app] not configured`. How can I add schema information on the Validator in the RegisterController

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:app.users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to change the users table name? What you have changed so far is good, but it seems your database configuration is off.

If you are trying to access the schema app and table users, then you can set the database config in either your .env file like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=app
DB_USERNAME=foo
DB_PASSWORD=bar
```

or in config/database.php (under the database driver). For example, if you're using MySql it looks like this:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'app',
            'username'  => 'foo',
            'password'  => 'bar',
        ],
```

Comment: I already configured database.php and .env settings. I have no issues on that side. The problem is on migration. I am using SQL server management studio, I noticed that if I do not add a schema,my username/domain name will be automatically set as default schema. The problem is that if someone git pulls my work from the team and they migrate, they will not see the database i created.

Answer (score 0):

In your `database.php` you have to configure the App database too to which you are referring.

```
   'app' => [
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'database'  => 'app',
                'username'  => 'foo',
                'password'  => 'bar',
            ],


    'mysql' => [
                    'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'host'      => 'localhost',
                    'database'  => 'app',
                    'username'  => 'foo',
                    'password'  => 'bar',
                ],
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, I have no issues on configuration, My issue is in schema information on the Validator in the RegisterController

Comment: @Led if your default connection is `app` then you dont need to speicfy the connection

Comment: my host is somehost/somedb and my database is `Inventories`. inside `Inventories` there are schemas and 1 schema i need to use is called `App`. This is a sample query: `use Inventories Select * from App.users`